# Is there a way to build an xsl stylesheet that filters given xml with multiple identical node names and obtain the result described below

Tags: xml, xslt

Given this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <results>
        <activityDescription>reservation</activityDescription>
    </results>
    <results>
        <studentSet>year1</studentSet>
        <studentSet>year2</studentSet>
        <studentSet>year3</studentSet>
        <studentSet>year4</studentSet>
        <activityDescription>Math</activityDescription>
    </results>
    <results>
        <studentSet>1g</studentSet>
        <studentSet>2h</studentSet>
        <studentSet>3j</studentSet>
        <studentSet>4k</studentSet>
        <activityDescription>Science</activityDescription>
    </results>
    <results>
        <studentSet>year 2</studentSet>
        <activityDescription>XSL/XML</activityDescription>
    </results>
</root>
```

and this XSLT code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:param name="year" select="1"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
  <body>
    <h2>Schedules</h2>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <th>Activity</th>
        <th>Year</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//results[contains(studentSet,$year)]">
      <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="activityDescription" /></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="studentSet" /></td>
      </tr>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </table>
  </body>
  </html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The results show two rows (math, science) for param $year = 1, but none for $year = 4, because the contains() function only looks at the first . How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `results[studentSet[contains(.,$year)]]` instead.